# Real-time WebGrid .NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

i I have this gridview running on partial view but i would like to update the data as on every update of the DB or every 3 seconds?

the partial view gets called from a index.cshtml with just the called and model passed to it.
@Html.Partial("_CommissionDeskReport", Model)

I tried using javascript but that kept on refreshing the whole page than the partial view.

here is the partial view code and please do advice?

_CommissionDeskReport.cshtml

```html
@model IEnumerable<Socks.Domain.Models.CommissionDeskReport>

@{
    Layout = null;
    //WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage: 3);
}

<h2>Commission Desk Report</h2>

<div id="EmployeeViewGrid">
    @{
        var grid1 = new WebGrid(source: Model, canPage: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
        @grid1.GetHtml(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All, tableStyle: "webGrid",
            headerStyle: "header",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
            selectedRowStyle: "select",
            rowStyle: "row",
            htmlAttributes: new { id = "employeeGrid" },
            fillEmptyRows: false,
            columns: grid1.Columns(
                grid1.Column("Period", header: "Period"),
                grid1.Column("Value", format: (item) => new HtmlString("£ " + Convert.ToString(item.value)), header: "Value"),
                grid1.Column("Average", format: (item) => new HtmlString("£ " + Convert.ToString(item.average)), header: "Average"),
                grid1.Column("Percent", format: (item) => new HtmlString(Convert.ToString(item.Percent) + " %"), header: "Percent"))
                
                
                
                )
    }
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .row {
        background: #fff;
    }

    .header {
        background: #bbb;
    }

    .alt {
        background: #d6e3f2;
    }

    .webGrid {
        border: 1px solid #bbb;
    }

        .webGrid th, .webGrid td {
            padding-left: 10px;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: For starters, your `ajaxUpdateContainerId` is wrong -- there is no div/container named `gridContent`, which would explain why the entire page is reloading.  Try `EmployeeViewGrid` instead.

Comment: Hi paul.abbott.wa.us there is no Ajax or JQuery code on this code. It is just a partial view with a web grid. I think you got mixed up with someone else’s code here.

However I found the solution with a very simple JQuery load call to the partial view, which code shall call this partial view method e.g. the code above; every 3 second and pass it to a <div>.

I'll upload the solution code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
// this will be you partial method on the controller

 public PartialViewResult CommissionDeskReportPartial()
        {
            List<Report> report = report.List(UserId).ToList();


            return PartialView("_CommissionDeskReport", report);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<script src="~/Scripts/lib/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            setInterval(function () {
                $('#gridView').load('CommissionDeskReportPartial');
            },
            3000);
        });
        
    </script>

    <div id="gridView">
    </div>

@*This code will go on your main view e.g Index.cshtml to call you partial method*@
```